# Problemas com getimagesize() PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema do qual gera o thumbnail conforme as imagens vem do BD abaixo:

```
/**
* $diretorio e $foto vem corretamente do BD quando o método é chamado
* O método encontra-se no diretório classes/
*/
    public function gerarThumb($diretorio,$foto){
       $diretorioNormal = '../'.$diretorio;
       $diretorioThumb = '../'.$diretorio."thumb/";
       $fotoDir = $diretorioNormal.$foto;
       echo '<img src="'.$fotoDir.'">';
       list($largura,$altura) = getimagesize($fotoDir);
       list($arquivo,$extensao) = explode(".",$foto);
       if($extensao == "jpg" || $extensao == "jpeg" || $extensao == "JPG"){
         if($largura > $altura){
            $novaLargura = 296;
            $novaAltura = 219;
            $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
            $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($fotoDir);
            imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
            imagejpeg($miniatura,$diretorioThumb.$foto,90);
         }
         if($altura > $largura){
           $novaLargura = 170;
           $novaAltura = 240;
           $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
           $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($fotoDir);
           imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
           imagejpeg($miniatura,$diretorioThumb.$foto,90);
         }
       }if($extensao == "png"){
         $miniaturaPNG = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
         $imagemPNG = imagecreatefrompng($fotoDir);
         imagecopyresampled($miniaturaPNG, $imagemPNG, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
         imagepng($miniaturaPNG,$diretorioThumb.$foto,null,90);
       }
       list($diretorio,$arquivo) = explode('../',$diretorioThumb);
       return $diretorio.$foto;
    }
```

O problema está no `getimagesize($fotoDir)`, que está aparecendo o erro abaixo:

```
Warning: getimagesize(../excursoes/excursao-para-teresopolis/6521db1ad10adce32b76a9b82f334b2bae690ef07e2a07d7bbd9b22c6eb0c1a187297f9054fd91f5d0fda5aa2d47cae6630911d23762fe5fec9e3ba75bb977f2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...
```

O que não estou conseguindo entender, é que dei um `echo` no método gerarThumb e a imagem aparece corretamente:

```
echo '<img src="'.$fotoDir.'">';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso corrigir isso? Vale lembrar que o GD está habilitado no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisar passar o local completo para que a função `getimagesize()` consiga encontrar a imagem.

Exemplo:

```
getimagesize('http://meusite.com/arquivos/imagem.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um

```
vardump($fotoDir);
```

e confirma se `$fotoDir` está como string.